# Is it possible to augment dataframes with time-series data for analysis in Convolutional Neural Networks?

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, time-series, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am trying to identify patterns in time-series data by using a convolutional neural network. However, due to limited number of observations (1500 in total), is it possible to augment the dataframes, similar to image augmentation without losing the relationship between time-series data? Just wondering what the best way is to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common way to augment data while keeping the relationship is to add random noise.

Additional methods that can work and lead to utilization in convolutional neural networks depending on the dataset is transformation of data into images followed by suitable augmentation techniques such as blurring or horizontal shifts.